# Python Selenium Element Click Behaving Strangeley

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Loading a site with Chromedriver and trying to click a link based on the text.

This is the site code for the link I'm looking for:

```
<div class="league_check" id="hr_selection_18359391" onclick="HorseRacingBranchWindow.showEvent(18359391);" title="Odds Available">                 
  <span class="race-status">
    <img src="/i/none_v.gif" width="12" height="12" onclick="HorseRacingBranchWindow.toggleSelection(18359391); cancelBubble(event);">
  </span>
  14:10 *
</div>
```

And I'm trying:

```
justtime = "14:10"
link = Driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(justtime)
link.click
```

I'm manually watching the browser it's loaded the data (including the link) before my code fires so it's not like it isn't there.

It's throwing a no such element exception. But I'm struggling to understand why. I use similar code all the time the only thing I can think is something with the site coding doesn't make the link text look like link text.

But I also tried

```
link = Driver.find_element_by_id("hr_selection_18359391")
```

And got the same result. Kind of stumped here would appreciate anyone who can shed some light on what I'm doing wrong.

/Update:

As pointed out below find_element_by_partial_link_text works on a tags not divs. Tried:

```
find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT(justtime))

link = Driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), justtime))")
```

But no dice there either. Guess I'm going to have to find another way to do this.

According to what I'm reading Xpath contains should be working. Even tried:

```
  link = Driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(.,'14:10 *      ')]")
        link.click()
```

Which gave me an attribute error.. which I find a little weird.

/Further down the rabbit hole:

So I thought maybe there's more than one link hidden in there somewhere. I tried:

```
justtime = "14:10"
links = Driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(.,justtime)]")
for eachlink in links:
 print eachlink.text
```

And it seemed to spit out every link the page had. Even though there's no reason for those DIVs to contain 14:10. So something must be wrong with my xpath but I can't see what.

Comment: Is this inside `frame` or `iframe` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

```
find_element_by_partial_link_text
```

Is working only on `<a>` tags, it won't work on `<div>`

`click` is a function, it should be

```
link.click()
```

And for the `find_element_by_id`, if the element is inside `<frame>` you need to switch to it first

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_id("id")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
# continue with the code
link = Driver.find_element_by_id("hr_selection_18359391")
link.click()
```

And to switch back

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Oops I'd forgotten to add the () to SO but the .click() in the code does have it at least.

Comment: Didn't know find_element_by_partial_link_text was only <a> that makes sense now. I had tried link = Driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'%s')]" % (justtime)) so I'm guessing that has the same restriction.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I didn't know selenium had to or even could swap to a specific frame. Doing that with the ID seems to go alright right up until the link.click() which then throws a selenium common error. This all said I'm going to back up and try to figure out if I can do this with XPATH instead of find_element_by_partial_link_text which would make things easier in general.