# Should be Simple XPATH?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

Using Python and Selenium I'm trying to click a link if it contains text. In this case say 14:10 and this would be the DIV I'm after.

```
<div class="league_check" id="hr_selection_18359391" onclick="HorseRacingBranchWindow.showEvent(18359391);" title="Odds Available">                <span class="race-status">                    <img src="/i/none_v.gif" width="12" height="12" onclick="HorseRacingBranchWindow.toggleSelection(18359391); cancelBubble(event);">                </span>14:10 *            </div>
```

I've been watching the browser move manually. I know the DIV has loaded before my code fires but I can't figure out what the heck it is actually doing.

Looked pretty straightforward. I'm not great at XPATH but I usually manage the basics.

```
justtime = "14:10"
links = Driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div*[contains(.,justtime)")
```

As far as I can see no other link on that page contains the text 14:10 but when I loop through links and print it out it's showing basically every link on that page.

I've tried to narrow it down to that class name and containing the text

```
justtime = "14:10"
links = Driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(.,justtime) and (contains(@class, 'league_check'))]")
```

Which doesn't return anything at all. Really stumped on this it's making no sense to me at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, your XPath didn't make use of `justtime` python variable. Instead, it references child element `<justtime>` which doesn't exists within the `<div>`. Expression of form `contains(., nonExistentElement)` will always evaulates to `True`, because `nonExistentElement` translates to empty string here. This is possibly one of the reason why your initial XPath returned more elements than the expected.

Try to incorporate value from `justtime` variable into your XPath by using string interpolation, and don't forget to enclose the value with quotes so that it can be properly recognized as XPath *literal string* :

```
justtime = "14:10"
links = Driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(.,'%s')]" % justtime)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to take a look. I understand how this works a little better now but I tried like this and links has nothing a loop through links has zero results even though I can see the div with 14:10 right there plain as day. Very annoying.

Comment: @PoweredByCoffee - Is that `div` within a `frame`? If yes, then make sure you switch to the `frame` as given in the [answer of your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35984110/2932244).

Comment: Aah that would make sense I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You have need to use wait for element

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'someid')))
```

Comment: Already covered in the question this is doe the data is there.